Two SMB servers behind one DNS name (same A records) not working for high availability
I am trying to resolve a problem with two samba file servers working behind same DNS name.
There are two servers, on which one SMB share is created. Sharing and NTFS rights settings are identical.
The task is to create two DNS A records with the name (example) fileserver-project1.domain.local with the IP addresses of two SMB servers.
When using the path \\fileserver-project1.domain.local\share, the first file server of the two file servers is always selected.
When the first server is disconnected (powered off), the path \\fileserver-project1.domain.local\share becomes unavailable, or a permission denied error occurs, or a repeated request for credentials occurs.
We also tried the registry value:
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters! DisableStrictNameChecking
Do I understand correctly that such a scheme will not work due to Kerberos and the lack of SPN in AD, and the inability to create an SPN on 2 Computer AD account, and the following solutions may be possible?:

Use DFS namespace
Use Windows failover file cluster service

I would be grateful for help in solving this issue.

Do I understand correctly that such a scheme will not work due to Kerberos and the lack of SPN? no, this is just a bogus design that can never work... But the failover cluster will work.
